# Metallurgical Junction

Tags: terminology, semiconductor-physics

I've been studying p-n junction. Then came the term "Metallurgical Junction". What's that? Metallurgical? I know its the study of metals and their properties. But why this is there in semiconductors? I don't know. The web's empty.

*kindly clear*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "metallurgical junction" is the transition location from the p-doped region to the n-doped region of a semiconductor. As such a junction is mostly produced by a heat driven diffusion of dopants into the semiconductor, which is a metallurgical process, it is called a "metallurgical junction". This is sometimes differentiated from the electrical junction which involves space charge (depletion) regions around the metallurgical junction.

Comment: Yeah! This question you actually cleared! what's your real name? why are you kinda afraid to tell me?

Comment: @Selena -Selena,  I assume this is your real name and that you are not really residing on the moon. You are so charmingly persistent that I have added my name to my profile.